# Vertically align the tops of matrices in an equation

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices

The following matrix equation looks great:

```
\begin{align*}
\overset{A}{\left[\begin{matrix}t_{1}&1\\ 
\vdots&\vdots\\
t_{n}&1
\end{matrix}\right]}
\overset{x}{\left[\begin{matrix}
x_{1}\\x_{2}
\end{matrix}\right]}
&=
\overset{b}{\left[\begin{matrix}
b_{1}\\ \vdots \\ b_{n}
\end{matrix}\right]}
\end{align*}
```

Except I am accustomed to having the tops of my matrices aligned when I write on scratch paper.  How can I accomplish this in LaTeX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A note before, [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides special `*matrix` environments:

- `pmatrix` for `( · )`
- `bmatrix` for `[ · ]`
- `Bmatrix` for `{ · }`
- `vmatrix` for `| · |`
- `Vmatrix` for `|| · ||`

## Solution 1

I used the `\vphantom` macro that resizes the box inside the `\overset` to same height like the other parts.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\biggestpart{}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\biggestpart{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    t_1    & 1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    t_n    & 1
  \end{bmatrix}
}
\begin{align*}
\overset{A}{\biggestpart}
\overset{x}{
  \vphantom{\biggestpart}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\ x_2
  \end{bmatrix}
}
&=
\overset{b}{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n
  \end{bmatrix}
}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

## Solution 2

As the second row in the bigger matrices are not of the same height of `x_2` the `\vphantom` command is used again (try it without to see the effect or replace `\vdots` with “normal” math stuff like `x_0`).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\overset{A}{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    t_1    & 1 \\
    \vdots & \vdots \\
    t_n    & 1
  \end{bmatrix}}
\overset{x}{
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\ x_2 \vphantom{\vdots}
  \end{bmatrix}}\\
  \\
  \end{array}
}
&=
\overset{b}{
  \begin{bmatrix}
    b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n
  \end{bmatrix}
}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: In the second solution, what does `@{}c@{}` do?

Comment: @alexpghayes `array` is the math version of `tabular`, its first argment is the column specification. `c` stands for a horizontally **c**entered column, `@{<stuff>}` inserts `<stuff>` between columns (or in this case before the first or after the last column) instead of the usual horizontal space. Since `<stuff>` is nothing we don't have any horizontal space between the content and the delimiters `[` and `]`.

Comment: @alexpghayes Internally, AMSmath uses `array` for its matrix environments in a similar way.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a *sans*-[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) version of [Qrrbrbirlbel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75176/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\matlabel}[2]{% \matlabel{<label>}{<stuff>}
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}} \mbox{\small$#1$} \\ #2 \end{array}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  \matlabel{A}{\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
      t_1 & 1 \\
      \vdots & \vdots \\
      t_n & 1
    \end{array}\right]}
  \matlabel{x}{\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      x_1 \\ \vphantom\vdots x_2 \\
    \end{array}\right] \\
    \mathstrut}\mathrel{\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}{=}}
  \matlabel{b}{\left[\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
      b_1 \\ \vdots \\ b_n
    \end{array}\right]}
\]
\end{document}
```

The only major difference is the setting of the matrix label as an element in an "vertical `array`", rather than an "upper limit in a math operator." As a consequence, the vertical alignment with respect to the mathematical axis has to be adjusted... using `\mathrel{\raisebox{-.5\normalbaselineskip}{=}}`.

Answer (score 2):

This is janky but I wanted something dead simple so I just wrapped a `\raisebox{0.5em}{$ [matrix goes here] $}` around the matrix that was too low and adjusted the distance until it looked ok.

Note, `\raisebox` seems to put you back into text mode so you have to wrap the matrix in `$ $`.

Before:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
x^T x:  
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
```

After:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
    x^T x:  
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    x_1 \\
    x_2 \\
    x_3
    \end{bmatrix}
    \raisebox{1.15em}{$
    \begin{bmatrix} 
    x_1 & x_2 & x_3\\
    \end{bmatrix}
    $}
\end{align*}
```